# Doubt about $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Arg}{Arg}$
The definition is $\Arg(z)=\{\arg(z)+2k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\arg(z)\in[0;2\pi)$

But, can I write $\Arg(z)$ without respecting the $\arg(z)$ form? For example, $\Arg(z)=\{-3\pi+2k\pi\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Notice that $\arg(z)$ cannot be $-3\pi$ but $-3\pi$ can be a value of $\Arg(z)$.

I'm asking because I have the following problem :

Determine $|z|$ and $|\Arg(z)$ for: $z=\underbrace{\sin a}_{2\sin\frac{a}{2}\cos\frac{a}{2}}+\underbrace{(1+\cos a)}_{2\cos^2\frac{a}{2}}\quad i,a\in\mathbb{R}$

$z=2\cos\frac{a}{2}(\sin\frac{a}{2}+i\cos\frac{a}{2})=2\cos\frac{a}{2}(\cos\frac{\pi-a}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi-a}{2})$.

Also $z=-2\cos\frac{a}{2}(\cos\frac{3\pi-a}{2}+i\sin\frac{3\pi-a}{2})$.

Since $|z|>0$ we have $|z|=2|\cos\frac{a}{2}|$

$\cos\frac{a}{2}\ge0\Rightarrow a\in[-\pi+4k\pi;\pi+4k\pi]$

$cos\frac{a}{2}<0\Rightarrow a\in(\pi+4k\pi;3\pi+4k\pi)$

So $\Arg(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\pi-a}{2}+2n\pi & a\in[-\pi+4k\pi;\pi+4k\pi] \\ \frac{3\pi-a}{2}+2n\pi & a\in(\pi+4k\pi;3\pi+4k\pi)\end{cases}$

$\frac{\pi-a}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi-a}{2}$ might not be in $[0;2\pi)$, but the $\Arg(z)$ set is still correct.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In some sense this is the point of Arg; so that you don't have to worry so much about the "representative" angle.

You have to make a small argument to show that for any real $\theta$, there is some complex number $w$ such that $\{\theta + 2k\pi | k\in\Bbb{Z}\}=\text{Arg}(w)$ as sets, but this is of course true (arguably already needed to define little arg).

As for your problem, I don't see any major issue. A small one: in your final answer the variable $k$ is overloaded; it is being used both as "an arbitrary integer" for use in $\text{Arg}(z)$, and also "the specific integer such that $a\in [(4k-1)\pi,(4k+3)\pi)$".

Comment: Got it! I will replace $k$ with $n$.